# Derivative of vector with vectorization

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, optimization, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus

I have these constraints on a cost function

$$
c = A+Bx=A+B\text{vec}\ (q^*q^\top),
$$
where $(c,A)\in\mathbb{R}^{100}$, $B\in\mathbb{C}^{100\times 81}$, $x\in\mathbb{C}^{81}$ and $q\in\mathbb{C}^9$. So $x=\text{vec}\ (q^*q^\top)$, which is the vectorization operator. I want to speed up my optimizer and therefore i require the gradient of the constraints (with respect to $q$). This is how far i have come:

$$
\begin{aligned}
dc = Bdx &= Bd\text{vec}\ (q^*q^\top)\\
&=B\text{vec}\ (q^*dq^\top+dq^*q^\top) \\
&=B\text{vec}\ (q^H:dq)+B\text{vec}\ (q^\top:dq^*)
\end{aligned}
$$

However, i cannot seem to get rid of the $\text{vec}$ operator. If i "matricize" the left side to remove the vectorization at the right side, i cannot get to $\frac{\partial c}{\partial q}$ anymore. Anyone got some brilliance for me?

**Update**: The last line of my derivation is incorrect i think. $q^H\in\mathbb{C}^{12}$ while $dq\in\mathbb{C}^{1\times 12}$, so you cannot use the Frobenius product here.

Comment: As things are written, you apparently have a vector-valued "cost function". With that, it's not clear what "minimizing" the cost would entail nor what its gradient should be

Comment: No, these are constraints on the cost function, not the cost function itself. The cost function is a scalar, i have 100 constraints on the cost function. Each constraint has a gradient with respect to $q$. There was a typo in the question tho, sorry!

Comment: Whoops! My mistake, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Another point of confusion: what is $\operatorname{vec}(q^H : dq)$? Typically, $A : B$ is a scalar quantity

Comment: Yes that does not seem correct, since they have different dimensions. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outer product of two vectors can be vectorized in several equivalent ways
$$\eqalign{
{\rm vec}(q^*q^T) &= {\rm vec}(q^*q^TI) = {\rm vec}(Iq^*q^T) \\
=q\otimes q^* &= (I\otimes q^*)\,q = (q\otimes I)\,q^* \\
}$$
Use this to rewrite the constraint vector and calculate its gradient(s).
$$\eqalign{
(c-A) &= B(I\otimes q^*)\,q \;=\; B(q\otimes I)\,q^* \\
dc &= B(I\otimes q^*)\,dq + B(q\otimes I)\,dq^* \\
\frac{\partial c}{\partial q} &= B(I\otimes q^*), \quad
\frac{\partial c}{\partial q^*} = B(q\otimes I) \\
}$$

Answer (score 2):

So far, you have
$$
dc = B \operatorname{vec}(q^*\,dq^\top) + B\operatorname{vec}(dq^*\, q^\top).
$$
To obtain the components of the gradient, it suffices to plug in $q = e_j$ (where $e_1,\dots,e_9$ denote the standard basis vectors). So, we have
$$
\frac{\partial c}{\partial q_j} = B \operatorname{vec}(q^*\,e_j^\top) + B\operatorname{vec}(e_j\, q^\top).
$$
We could rewrite this in terms of the Kronecker product to "unvectorize". Note that $\operatorname{vec}(v w^T) = w \otimes v$, so that
$$
\frac{\partial c}{\partial q_j} = B (e_j \otimes q^*) + B(q \otimes e_j).
$$

---

Another option is to go in the opposite direction: instead of vectorizing, unvectorize everything. Suppose that we have
$$
B = \sum_{j=1}^k P_j \otimes Q_j,
$$
with $P_j,Q_j$ of size $10 \times 3$ (such a decomposition can be computed with reshaping and either SVD or rank factorization). We then have
$$
B \operatorname{vec}(q^*q^T) = \sum_{j=1}^k P_j \otimes Q_j \operatorname{vec}(q^*q^T) \\
= \sum_{j=1}^k \operatorname{vec}(Q_jq^*q^TP_j^T) \\
= \sum_{j=1}^k \operatorname{vec}(Q_jq^*(P_jq)^T).
$$
In other words, if we unvectorize $c$ into the $10 \times 10$ matrix $C$, then we have
$$
C = [\text{const.}] + \sum_{j=1}^k (Q_jq^*(P_jq)^T).
$$

Comment: $e_j$ is simply (0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) where $j$ determines the position of the 1, right (so in this case $j=2$? With the latter derivation, to get $\frac{\partial c}{\partial q}$, you need to reshape $\frac{\partial C}{\partial q}$ accordingly, if i am not mistaken?

Comment: Yes, that's all correct.